# Array keeping values after the end of the code

Tags: arrays, vba, excel, variables, storage

I was wondering if there is a way to keep some values stored in an array after the code ends and the excel file is closed.

The idea would be to have an array containing some values. When running the code, I might or might not modify some of its values and when I close the file I'd like this array to subsist and keep its values.
What I mean by that is that when I would re-open the file and run the code, all the other variables would be re-initialised (and obviously would get default values again), but this special array would still have all its values stored (so I would of course not re-declare it in that code).

One way to avoid this trouble would be to store all the values contained in the array in a worksheet and whenever the code is run again, put them back into a new array.
But I am wondering if there is a way to do this without using a worksheet.

Comment: Try [Workbook.CustomDocumentProperties Property (Excel)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/workbook-customdocumentproperties-property-excel).  I've never used it, but it may work for your purpose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One tends to think of a worksheet as the heart and soul of Excel and is, therefore, reluctant to make "such a big effort" to store just one array. From Excel's point of view a sheet is nothing more than an array, taking up just a few bytes of memory while it is empty. I would argue that a VeryHidden worksheet is precisely what you are asking for, in fact very similar to Word's Document Variables.

As an alternative I could suggest using one of the built-in properties, such as Keywords or Comments, to store a string which can be Split into an array. This would probably be more to your liking but I think it is inferior because the user can edit it, unless that is something you can use to your advantage.

Technically, and for all practical purposes, a VeryHidden worksheet is precisely what you are asking for. Your resistance is based in psychology, not reason - at least, that is how I convinced myself, and I can say being more liberal with the number of worksheets I create has given me more liberties at no perceptible cost.

Comment: Thanks. I think the best option in my case is a hidden (or very hidden sheet maybe). I expected to find a way to keep an **array** variable stored in the file but apparently, as @David G showed, it is not possible.

Is there any different between a very hidden and hidden sheet apart from the fact that one is totally unaccessible form the user interface ? Like memory-wise maybe ?

Comment: A workbook with all its data (and sheets) is actually a collection of xml files. You can check this by yourself, just rename your `file.xlsx` to `file.zip` and unzip it. Storing your data within a (hidden) sheet will be the very same as storing it within Document Properties when it comes to memory. It is text, stored in xml files. The hidden sheet naturally will give you more tools.

Comment: No. The only difference is the accessibility from the keyboard.

Answer (score 1):

Either store information, as you mentioned, within a (hidden) sheet, or use [Document Variables](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/word-vba/articles/storing-values-when-a-macro-ends).

From the documentation:

```
Sub AddDocumentVariable() 
 ActiveDocument.Variables.Add Name:="Age", Value:=12 
End Sub
```

These variables will be available even if your code has finished or the workbook was closed and opened again.

Edit: (for excel, code found [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/word-vba/articles/storing-values-when-a-macro-ends))

```
Sub test()
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim docProps As DocumentProperties
Dim docProp As DocumentProperty
        Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
        Set docProps = wb.CustomDocumentProperties

     With docProps
             .Add Name:="CustomNumber", _
                        LinkToContent:=False, _
                        Type:=msoPropertyTypeNumber, _
                        Value:=1000
             .Add Name:="CustomString", _
                        LinkToContent:=False, _
                        Type:=msoPropertyTypeString, _
                        Value:="This is a custom property."
             .Add Name:="CustomDate", _
                        LinkToContent:=False, _
                        Type:=msoPropertyTypeDate, _
                        Value:=Date
     End With
        For Each docProp In docProps
             Debug.Print docProp.Name, docProp.Value
     Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for that lead. Seems like this is only valid for Word documents though. I am trying to find the same thing for Excel.

Comment: This is exactly what I am looking for but for an array variable. As explained in the post you've linked, if the type is array, there is no msoPropertyType for it. So I should create a variable to store each element of my array (36 in my case...could be worse though). Therefore array-wise the best solution seems to be using a (very) hidden sheet